# Output SQL query in PHP in uppercase

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with some information, I didn't think about making the insert query in uppercase. I have a page where I show those information and I would like to know if on PHP side there's a way to conver those information in uppercase only on the user end, so in the database would be still in lowercase. This is my PHP to print the SQL query

```
if (!empty($_POST['sede'])){
$sql = "SELECT ID, nome, cognome, codicefiscale, sedelavoro, datanascita, lingua, errori, risultato, datatest FROM testlingua WHERE sedelavoro='$sede' ORDER BY ID";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>". $row["ID"]. "</td><td>". $row["nome"]. "</td><td>" . $row["cognome"]. "</td><td>" .$row["codicefiscale"]. "</td><td>" .$row["sedelavoro"]. "</td><td>" .$row["datanascita"]. "</td><td>" .$row["lingua"]. "</td><td>" .$row["errori"]. "</td><td>" .$row["risultato"]. "</td><td>" .$row["datatest"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "Nessun Risultato";
}
```

Can I show everything in uppercase without touching the SQL itself?

Comment: [`strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

Comment: .. or `SELECT UPPER(columnName) FROM table_name`

Comment: Instead of implementing a workaround, so trying to cure the symptom, you should fix the actual cause, so migrate your data.

Comment: Depending on how `$sede` is set you might be open to SQL injections. It is best to parameterize. Also if `$sede` is `$_POST['sede']` you should empty check the variable. That way you'll only need to change the index once if you change the name later.

Comment: @user3783243 Thanks for the advice, I didn't post the full code since it was not relevant for the question. arkascha I know I have to, I will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of echoing the stuff directly, you could do this and make use of `strtoupper` (which was already linked by Nick):

```
    $str = "<tr><td>". $row["ID"]. "</td><td>". $row["nome"]. "</td><td>" . $row["cognome"]. "</td><td>" .$row["codicefiscale"]. "</td><td>" .$row["sedelavoro"]. "</td><td>" .$row["datanascita"]. "</td><td>" .$row["lingua"]. "</td><td>" .$row["errori"]. "</td><td>" .$row["risultato"]. "</td><td>" .$row["datatest"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo strtoupper($str);
```

Comment: That was my guess but I tried $row = strtoupper($row)

Comment: $row isn't a string, but an array. That's why it won't work.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right! I missed that...It worked, thanks a lot! I will mark it as correct as soon as I can

Comment: @TheNoobUser `array_map('strtoupper', $row)` is probably a better approach. That way only your values will be uppercased. e.g. https://3v4l.org/D1gDZ

Answer (score 0):

You can try the SQL using UPPER :

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, UPPER(nome), UPPER(cognome), UPPER(codicefiscale), UPPER(sedelavoro), UPPER(datanascita), UPPER(lingua), UPPER(errori), UPPER(risultato), UPPER(datatest) FROM testlingua WHERE sedelavoro='$sede' ORDER BY ID";
```